# Deploying Apache at Customer Site - Appliance - how to deploy cert?

Tags: ssl

Here's the deal:
Need to deploy an OVA to a customer site.  The OVA contains Apache for HTTPS.  The name space when deployed will be i.e. server.xyz.customer.net.   Of course any SSL certs I deploy with the machine won't be for *.customer.net   -

How does one handle this situation?  How do I get SSL traffic for my Apache instance deployed at a customer site?  Am I forced to ask the customer for certificates in order to do such a deploy?

Suggestions or guides?

Comment: Ummm..... What?

Comment: Why won't the certs be for *.customer.net? Why can't you get a cert for *.xyz.customer.net and deploy with that?

Comment: You could use lets encrypt to generate a certificate on the fly - once the machine is booted and the DNS record is pointing at your host, you have the requirements to generate a certificate. With that said, you should probably check with your clients security policies or DNS CAA records first.

Comment: @BrennenSmith I don't think you should assume that the machine will be connected to the internet on installation, much less that any firewalls in the network will allow it to talk to Letsencrypt.

Comment: Given that neither of us know the environment it will be running in, it would be rude to not provide a potential solution. It’s up to esch to decide what the best solution is for their given scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you set a default cert, oftentime with just the 'productname' short name, and provide the tech at the end organization a way to easily change it during setup.